# R Shiny : non-reactive text output

Tags: r, shiny

I am just trying to write output to a textOutput but I don't want it responding to any reactives - I want total control of when I update the text (for notifications: I want to basically write some log messages based on backend processing to the screen).

If I add: `verbatimTextOutput("txt")` in my ui.R and then try to do:

```
observeEvent(input$someButton, {
 ... # do some work
 output$txt <- "some text" #Error: see below
 ... # do some more work
})
```

I am getting *Warning: Unhandled error in observer: Unexpected character output for txt*

**ADDED**: reproducible example:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$doBtn, {
    #...  do some work
    output$txt <- "some text" #crashes app.
    #... do some more work
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("txt"),
    actionButton("doBtn", "Do something")
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is it even possible to directly reference a text output element in this way, without wrapping it in its own render* function? I don't think I can take the error message too literally because the text being updated is very simple. And yes I am aware of withProgress() etc but that is not what I want in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be a little more helpful to see a reproducible example for further context.  Generally if you want to return text you would use `renderText` or `renderUI`.

Comment: @cdeterman added now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want the output to the screen, you can still use `renderText` within your `observeEvent`.  I included an additional text message to demonstrate the use of `htmlOutput` in case you don't want that box around the text.

```
require(shiny)

runApp(
    list(
        ui = pageWithSidebar(
            headerPanel("text test"),
            sidebarPanel(
                p("Demo Page."),
                actionButton("doBtn", "Do something")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                verbatimTextOutput("txt"),
                htmlOutput("text2")
            )
        ),
        server = function(input, output){

            observeEvent(input$doBtn, {
                #... # do some work
                output$txt <- renderText("some text")
                #... # do some more work
            })

            output$text2 <- renderUI({
                HTML("my awesome text message in HTML!!!")
            })

        }
    )
)
```

On the other hand, if you just need something to print to the console you could just use `cat` as shown in the documentation of `?observerEvent`

```
observeEvent(input$doBtn, {
        cat("some text")
})
```

Comment: I have several different built via shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server). The above does not work within that scheme, I keep getting "Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use".  But this does work when you wrap everyrthing in in runApp() as shown. Btw - is your method the preferred / better way to build a multifile shiny app? I have just been copying the reference examples.

Comment: Never mind... it seems I need to source the file and run it directly instead of using runApp. Anyway it works! thanks!

Comment: @rstruck, I only use the `runApp` method for quick, self-contained answers.  If I have a larger example I always use the traditional `ui.R` and `server.R` files but using use a git gist for the answer.